# How to install Python using Windows Command Prompt

Tags: python, cmd, installation, python-install

Is it possible to install Python from cmd on Windows? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Yes for example u can use this [Non-interactive Installation](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/msi/)

Comment: Thanks @Thaian! Works great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Python with cmd or powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578270/install-python-with-cmd-or-powershell)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui

> Installing Without UI: All of the options available in the installer UI
>   can also be specified from the command line, allowing scripted
>   installers to replicate an installation on many machines without user
>   interaction. These options may also be set without suppressing the UI
>   in order to change some of the defaults.
>
> To completely hide the installer UI and install Python silently, pass
>   the /quiet option. To skip past the user interaction but still display
>   progress and errors, pass the /passive option. The /uninstall option
>   may be passed to immediately begin removing Python - no prompt will be
>   displayed.
>
> All other options are passed as name=value, where the value is usually
>   0 to disable a feature, 1 to enable a feature, or a path.

Answer (score 3):

I have used windows powershell to achieve this..

1. Download Python Exe File..Feel free to edit 'URI' for the updated version of python & outFile for your preferred windows location

   Invoke-WebRequest  -UseBasicParsing -Uri  'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/python-3.11.0-amd64.exe' -OutFile 'c:/veera/python-3.11.0-amd64.exe'
2. install python via command prompt

   .\python-3.11.0-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0
3. set python location

   setx /M path "%path%;C:\Program Files\Python311"

   $env:PATH =$env:PATH+";C:\Program Files\Python311"

you're good to use python from  command now :)

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows**

I was unable to find a way to Download python using just CMD but if you have python.exe in your system then you can use the below Method to install it  (you can also make .bat file to automate it.)

1. Download the python.exe file on your computer from the official site.
2. Open CMD and change Your directory to the path where you have python.exe
3. Past this code in your Command prompt make sure to change the name with your file version In the below code(e.g python-3.8.5.exe)

`python-3.6.0.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0`

It will also set the path Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `python-installer.exe` file you can run in in `/passive` mode in administrator window. Without administrator privileges you will be prompted

*Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?*

Powershell example could be:

```
$installer = "C:/tmp/python-3.7.6-amd64.exe"
& $installer /passive InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0
```

Comment: umm but it will not automatically set the path variable right?

Comment: @KhanSaad I do not understand why you downvoted that and based you answer on exactly the same statement. `PATH` will behave the same way in with both flags `/passive` or `/quiet`. If you have noticed different behaviour perhaps command like was not refreshed.

Comment: I am sorry, I was frustrated with a code, Change something in the answer and I will upvote again

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/), e.g., `winget install -e --id Python.Python.3.11`. Should work out of the box in Windows 11 and modern installations of Windows 10 - according to the docs.

> The winget command line tool enables users to discover, install,
> upgrade, remove and configure applications on Windows 10 and Windows
> 11 computers. This tool is the client interface to the Windows Package
> Manager service.