# How can Python 3 be installed from command line without user input required?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-3.6, macos-high-sierra

I am running macOS High Sierra.

I have a .pkg installer. Using [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) I cannot add shell scripts without permission issues, so I used Automator to wrap the package and run some commands before and after installation. I want this shell script, run from Automator, to install Python 3, as it is a dependency of the application I am trying to install. The most commonly suggested option is to use Homebrew, but since this application will be installed on accounts without admin permissions, I can't do that. For reference, I don't need Python 3 installed system-wide (though that would be nice), just for it to run my application. Last thing - I tried rewriting the Python 3 code in Python 2 since that runs natively in macOS but for some reason I find "no matching distributions" when using pip to install the packages I need, all of which definitely have Python 2.7 support.

TL;DR: Is there a way to install Python 3 in such a way that it requires no user input and no admin permissions?

Comment: *"Is there a way to install Python 3 in such a way that it requires no user input and no admin permissions"* I certainly hope the answer is **"no"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Python using Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056161/how-to-install-python-using-windows-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a full install on raspbian.
There are ways you can do it on windows too.
This might help:

> - https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056265/10879012